# Uncaught TypeError: product_slider.owlCarousel is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

I am having troubles adding this carousel (OWL CAROUSEL) to my template.

It returns me the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: product_slider.owlCarousel is not a function
```

And the code using to initialize it is this one

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    //top product slider
    var product_slider = $('#product-slider');
    if(product_slider.length == 1) {
        product_slider.on('initialized.owl.carousel', function(e) {
            product_slider.find('.owl-dot').css('width', (100 / e.item.count) + '%');
        });
        product_slider.owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            nav: true,
            navText: false,
            smartSpeed: 1200,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayHoverPause: true,
            loop: true
        });
    }
```

Comment: Could you paste the html where you are loading the owl carousel libraries?

Comment: 99% of these errors is a missing library or loading the important library BEFORE jQuery. You MUST have somewhere `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` followed by `<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>` and only ONE jQuery.js - e.g. no jquery.js or jquery.min.js after the first one

Comment: <div id="product-slider" class="owl-pagination-dash owl-navigation-box"><img alt="product" src="assets/images/slider/Hotel_Amrut_Tullya.jpg"></div>

Comment: This attached js file
 <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/owl-carousel2/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
        <script src="assets/js/raphael-min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>

Comment: @user3501076 just remove jquery/1.9.0 b'coz already included jquery-1.11.3.min.js. working very well.